# Cut line label on tile border in geoserver tile cache

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have a problem with line label clipped on tile boundary. For point layer labels, it was solved by using "buffer" parameter in tile caching option and using "partials" in SLD. But in my opinion, labelling in line is dynamic, not fixed label. So I can't solve this problem using buffer and partials. How can I solve this problem? I'm beginner in GeoServer.

Here are my tile cache option.

- meta tile size : 8*8
- gutter size : 100
- image format : png8
- tile image : 512*512
- labeling vendor option

  ```
  <sld:VendorOption name="allowOverruns">false</sld:VendorOption>
  <sld:VendorOption name="followLine">true</sld:VendorOption>
  <sld:VendorOption name="group">true</sld:VendorOption>
  <sld:VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">25.0</sld:VendorOption>
  <sld:VendorOption name="charSpacing">5</sld:VendorOption>
  <sld:VendorOption name="partials">true</sld:VendorOption>
  ```

I think there are two alternatives(avoid label or label). But I don't know how to that.

1. How can I avoid line label overlap with tile border? (I have tile border layer.)
2. How can I solve clipped line label?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a cut label then you should turn off `partials` which is the option that tells GeoServer that you know best and it can cut a label.

If you want labels that can cross a tile boundary then you need to make sure that GeoServer draws the label in the same place on both tiles. There are several functions that can be used to fix a label point on a line, `startPoint`, `endPoint`, `centroid`, `pointN`.